# ExpressionEngine Automatic Category if not one set

Tags: categories

I have a channel called blog, and i have just created a category group with some categories. I have assigned the group to the the channel "blog", as it stands each entry has no category assigned, is it possible to use a default category for the exisiting and new entries created until another is selected.

For example:

Categories:

```
General
Another category
Another category
Another category
```

Basically all the entries to automatically have General as a category unless i go into the entry and chance to a different category.

Or do i have to go into every entry and set a category?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default category for all entries in a channel within the preferences for that channel.

Admin->Channels->Edit preferences

However if you mean that you want a category set *unless* another category is selected then you would need to use some kind of conditional statement in your template to pull entries that are not in any category.

I'd think about doing this using the category="not 1" parameter.

Comment: Superb, Thankyou as always. You replied to one of my questions i posted the other week about a postcode search and returning entries. Would it be possible to contact you about this i just need a nudge to get things working?

Thankyou.

Comment: Sure, just Google my username.